# Cropping image with RMagick removes anti-aliasing

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using RMagick to crop a large PNG file into tiles. The original PNG file is line art with a transparent background; the line edges are alpha blended to reduce jaggies. The tiles (also PNG files) are not alpha blended, and they look ugly. How do I preserve the alpha channel in the tiles?

Here's the code:

```
big_image = Image.read(png_file)[0]

0.upto(tileset['width'] - 1) do |x|
  0.upto(tileset['height'] - 1) do |y|
    # Snip the code that sets tile_filename

    # Find the region to crop
    left = x * 256
    # The Y axis goes bottom to top
    bottom = tileset['height'] * 256
    top = bottom - ((1 + y) * 256)

    tile = big_image.crop(left, top, 256, 256)
    tile.write(tile_filename)
  end
end
```

I've checked the `.alpha?` method -- it returns true for both `big_image` and `tile`. I've also tried calling `.alpha(ActivateAlphaChannel)` on both objects; it didn't help.